# How can I apply JUnit tests to my Insert(),update(),delete() methods without database dependency (with Mockito)

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, junit, mockito

I'll send my methods an entity as their parameters, meaning that I have already the information I want to insert, update or delete from my database. I injected the entitymanager with my persistence unit name so i know it works, the name of my entitymanager is "em". I mapped my classes from my database with a database connection, the class that I'm working on is named by "TipoUsuario" These are my methods:

```
public void insert(TipoUsuario tipoUsuario) throws Exception {
    if (em != null) {
        em.persist(tipoUsuario);
    }
}

public void update(TipoUsuario tipoUsuario) throws Exception {
    if (em != null) {
        em.merge(tipoUsuario);
    }

}

public void delete(TipoUsuario tipoUsuario) throws Exception {
    if (em != null) {
        em.remove(tipoUsuario);
    }
}
```

I was working on the first method (insert) but I don't know how to test my method... This is my method to test insert method:

```
@Test
public void testInsert() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("insert");
    TipoUsuario tipoUsuario = new TipoUsuario(1, "Mantenedor", "AC2354", true);
    //Instance of my class where I have my insert, update and delete methods
    Utilidades instance = new Utilidades();
    //I mock an entity manager with annotation @Mock and I pass that mocked entitytmanager to my the entitymanager that I have in my main class 
    instance.em = this.em;
    //and that's all i got.. I don't know how to test if it really works
    //i send my entity to my methor insert
    instance.insert(tipoUsuario);
    //i dont know what is return o how to use the assertEquals in this case...
    assertEquals( ?,  ?);
}
```

I mocked the entitymanager because that's not part of my code and i know other have tested before,the only thing I want to test is if my method insert the information to the database.

I'll appreciate any idea that you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Mockito.verify(em, Mockito.times(1)).persist(tipoUsuario);
```

To see if the persist method was called 1 time.

Comment: By knowing that the method was called, can i be sure that my data was persisted?

Comment: depends how much you trust the entitymanager.  the only way to be sure is to also add a select(...) method as well and you can do an insert then do the select and see if it's in there.

Answer (score 0):

> I mocked the entitymanager because that's not part of my code and i
>   know other have tested before,the only thing I want to test is if my
>   method insert the information to the database.

if entitymanager  is mocked then method calls on it are not real so there would be no real updates to DB. As Answered by Charles, you can only verify that method was indeed called one time and only once but verifying data doesn't make sense to me if entity manager is mocked.

Doing real time inserts ( or any real db call for that matter ) as part of unit tests is not desirable as unit tests are usually run at build time and real DB might not be available at that time. If a failing unit test means that your build is failed then you will be in trouble.

If you really wish to do that, try to accomplish your tests with some in - memory DB in the context of unit tests.

Also, what you are trying to accomplish might fall under integration test and not unit test - think on those lines.

If you are really interested in unit testing your JPA/ DAO/Data layer, have a look at Apache DBUnit and some other similar frameworks.

[About DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)

[JPAUnit - A replacement for DBUnit in JPA Unit Tests](https://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/jpaunit-java-jpa-unit-testing-library-replacement-dbunit)

[Unit Testing JPA... Stop Integration Testing!](https://dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-jpastop-integration-testing)